# How can I use an existing Firefox instance started manually for testing using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I use an existing Firefox instance for testing? I first want to do some manual testing with an instance I start manually and then I want to use the existing browser for my automation script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't possible.

It is one of the more older, yet most requested features for Selenium, see issue [18 in the Selenium tracker.](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=18&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary)

There are various technical reasons as to why it's difficult.

Your best bet would be to just have your test *not* quit at the end of a failing test, and have your *setup* procedure responsible for killing all open browser windows - it's not nice, but it would allow you to have a browser still open to inspect the application at the point of failure.

Comment: Resharing a browser window between tests works but it takes a careful understanding of usage of @Configuration methods in your test framework.  I think TestNG makes this a little easier but if you go that route, know that it is a little tricky but doable.

Comment: @Arran congratulations on making 10k by the way!